# Why can't I parse by a period in java?

Tags: java, parsing

I am looking to parse a string by ". ", but it seems to register the period as a backspace and then just parse by the space. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

```
String x = "Hi. My name is Jeffrey. I like sports.";
    for (String t : x.split(". "))
        System.out.println(t);
```

This yields:

M

nam

i

Jeffrey

(blank line)

lik

sports.

Comment: Split takes a regular expression, and a dot is a special token which matches any character.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

In regex, `.` matches any character. To match the literal period, escape the expression:

```
x.split("\\. ")
```